# align image to the right inside a button programmatically WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to align a image inside a button to the right. however it does not seem to do what i want it to do. i have been trying for several hours now, so i think it is time to ask here. this is my code atm.

```
public class DirectoryButton : Button
{
    public DirectoryButton(string name, string content)
    {
        Name = name.Replace(" ", "");
        //Content = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Resources/folder-icon.png", UriKind.Relative)) + content;
        //Content = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Resources/folder-icon.png", UriKind.Relative));
        var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Resources/folder-icon.png", UriKind.Relative));

        var sp = new UniformGrid
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
            Columns = 3,
            Rows = 1
        };
        sp.Children.Add(new Label());
        sp.Children.Add(new Label { Content = content, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center });
        sp.Children.Add(new Image { Source = img, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center});
        //sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        Content = sp;
        //Content = content;
        Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5);
        Height = 65;
        Width = 350;
        FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

[button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AfIg.png)

this makes the image in the button appear but it is not to the right. i cannot really do anything in the xaml since everything is created programmaticaly.

Regards,

Bjorn

Comment: How does the Button look like? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: is there a fast way to add images here? or do i need to upload to an image site?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: image added. just press the link

Comment: I guess you want the image to be at the right edge. So when you replace the `HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;` with `HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;` your inner `UniformGrid` will move to the right edge. Since the size of your `UniformGrid` will be only the size of the two labels and the image. The image is a the right edge of you centered inner grid.

Comment: @MartinBackasch sorry i don't really understand what u mean. can u explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`:

```
public class DirectoryButton : Button
{
    public DirectoryButton(string name, string content)
    {
        Name = name.Replace(" ", "");
        //Content = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Resources/folder-icon.png", UriKind.Relative)) + content;
        //Content = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Resources/folder-icon.png", UriKind.Relative));
        var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Resources/folder-icon.png", UriKind.Relative));

        var sp = new UniformGrid
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
            Columns = 3,
            Rows = 1
        };
        sp.Children.Add(new Label());
        sp.Children.Add(new Label { Content = content, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center });
        sp.Children.Add(new Image { Source = img, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center });
        //sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        Content = sp;
        //Content = content;
        Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5);
        Height = 65;
        Width = 350;
        FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch; //<--
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

This should make the `UniformGrid` stretch to fill the entire `Button` and the `Image` will then end up to the right.

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to explain in the comments above.

The code you've provide us works like it should.

You create an `UniformGrid` with three cells and add three childs to the grid.
Each cell of the grid will have the same size.

Your empty label will got to the left one. The next label to the center.
You will add your image to the right cell and set `HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right`. This will align your image within his cell at the right edge. And also to the right edge of your grid.

Now you add your `UniformGrid` as `Content` to your button.
With the following line of code

```
HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

you will center your grid within the button. 
That's why your image is not at the right edge of your button.

---

As already suggested in my comment you can set

```
HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

and your Image **and** the whole grid will move to the right edge, but this means also that your centered Label will also move to the right.

---

If you want to let the second `Label` stay within the center of the Button take the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47162860/5893316) provided by [mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7252182/mm8) and use 
`HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;`